# VS Code sfdx-scanner installation error related to SSL

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode

I am trying to install **Salesforce sfdx-scanner** for *VS code* on my office laptop as per the below guideline
[Install and Update Salesforce Code Analyzer](https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/en/v3.x/getting-started/install/).
I checked some of the issues related to sfdx-scanner but none of them faced this issue.

But I am getting below-error

```
sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-scanner

Polling for new version(s) to become available on npm... done
Successfully validated digital signature for @salesforce/sfdx-scanner.
Finished digital signature check.
Installing plugin @salesforce/sfdx-scanner... | [1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@salesforce%2fsfdx-scanner: write EPROTO 5C6A0000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\statem\\extensions.c:922:
Installing plugin @salesforce/sfdx-scanner... failed
    Error: C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js add @salesforce/sfdx-scanner@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:\Users\rachit\AppData\Local\sf\yarn.lock
    --preferred-cache-folder=C:\Users\rachit\AppData\Local\sf\yarn --check-files exited with code
```